# Pegar apenas um valor do mysqli_fetch_assoc

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer um código para controle de estoque usando PHP.
Cada vez que o usuário for usar o programa, este deve selecionar um funcionário e partir disso selecionar o resto dos campos conforme necessário.

Esta parte do código funciona perfeitamente:

```
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row[funcionario] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row[origem] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row[destino] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row[quantidade] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row[package] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row[conteudo] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row[sabor] ?></td>
            <td><b><a onclick="excluiProduto(<?php echo $row[id_saida] ?>)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" id="deleta"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"><span></a></td></b>
        </tr>
<?php


    }
    $func = $row[funcionario];
    echo $func;
?>
</table>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div style="padding-top: 20px" class=" center-block" >
        <form method="GET" action="imprimirRel.php">
        <button value="<?php echo $func ?>" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" style="<?php echo $mostraTabela ?>">Confirmar saída</button>
        </form>


    </div>
</div>
```

Agora estou tentando pegar esse valor e passar pra outra página afim de imprimir um relatório com o seguinte código:

```
<?php

    INCLUDE "conexao.php";

  $func = $_GET['submit'];
  echo $func; die;



    $sql = "SELECT * FROM controle_saida WHERE DATE(data_saida)=CURDATE() AND funcionario='".$func."'";
    //DATE(date)=CURDATE()
    $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==0){
        $mostraTabela = "display:none";
    }
    else {
        $mostraTabela = "";
    }


    ?>
```

O problema é que não estou conseguindo pegar esse funcionário pelo valor do submit, uma vez que este está fora do mysqli_fetch_assoc. Se eu colocar dentro, ele puxa todos os valores que vão aparecer dentro do loop while. 
Eu imagino que não esteja fazendo da melhor forma, existe alguma outra forma de fazer?
Lembrando que o funcionário não precisa estar dentro do loop, uma vez que a cada utilização todas as linhas terão apenas um funcionário, porém os outros campos se alteram.

---

MODIFICADO: 
O código que estou fazendo é pra controle de saída de produtos. Nele possuo o cadastro abaixo: 
[image: Cadastro de produtos]

Conforme completo o cadastro e clico em adicionar, eu adiciono na lista abaixo: [image: Lista de produtos]

O problema é: Imaginemos que estamos fazendo o cadastro do 3º funcionário, e utilizando apenas esse código:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM controle_saida WHERE DATE(data_saida)=CURDATE()";
```

Não será o suficiente para trazer a tabela apenas de um funcionário, e acabará trazendo todos os registros que foram feitos hoje, inclusivo dos outros 2 funcionários. 
Com isso o que quero é: Estou preenchendo o cadastro de produtos do Eduardo, quero chamar apenas nome dele na próxima pagina para imprimir um relatório, e não estou conseguindo fazer isso.

Comment: Não entendi.. Tem que aparecer um botão para cada funcionário isso? E depois preencher

Comment: Na verdade, você seleciona um funcionário e partir disso preenche o resto do relatório. É um controle de saída de produto, ou seja, como sairá uma página para impressão,não convém que seja feito com vários funcionários ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: $func = $row[funcionario]; echo $func; ele imprime o valor desejado ?

Comment: Isso funciona, mas como estou tratando de uma tabela, ele vai trazer todos os valores da tabela, uma vez que está dentro do while. Mesmo que fosse apenas um funcionário, Felipe por exemplo, no echo traria "Felipe Felipe Felipe Felipe"

Comment: E qual é o valor que você deseja, desculpa mas ainda não estou entendendo?

Comment: O correto seria explicares o que faz este teu sistema, ou como queres que ele funcione, e só depois poderias expor o problema.

Comment: Eu achei que tivesse explicado o suficiente. Já editei minha pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Felipe, deixa eu ver se entendi.

1. Crie uma coluna em sua tabela `controle_saida` com nome ex.: `id_funcionario`
2. Quando realizar o "Adicionar" passe o valor do `id` do funcionário da tabela onde está os funcionários que acredito ser outra para esta nova coluna `id_funcionario`.
3. Quando fizer a consulta na tabela `controle_saida`, faça assim:

.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM controle_saida WHERE DATE(data_saida)=CURDATE() AND id_funcionario = '".$func["id"]."'";
```

Comment: Isso funciona, mas como estou tratando de uma tabela, ele vai trazer todos os valores da tabela, uma vez que está dentro do while. Mesmo que fosse apenas um funcionário, Felipe por exemplo, no echo traria "Felipe Felipe Felipe Felipe"

Comment: Então, consegue nos passar o restante do código que vem antes? Para eu poder ver de onde e como está obtendo o valor `<td><?php echo $row[funcionario] ?></td>.........`

Comment: Vou modificar a pergunta já que não consegui deixar claro de entender.

Comment: Modifiquei minha resposta...

Comment: Thyago, acho que era isso que estava faltando, criar outra tabela para funcionários. Sou iniciante e ainda tenho problema em fazer um MER correto. Vou tentar e posto aqui a resposta, mas já vou dar como resposta correta, pois acredito que você está certo. Obrigado

Comment: Maravilha, fico feliz com isso... Quando quiser saber um pouco mais sobre isso que deseja fazer, pesquise por "Relacionamento de Tabelas", neste caso estamos fazendo uma "gambiarra" com relacionamento manualmente, veja opções de relacionamento 1:1 - 1:N - N:N Abraços!

Answer (score 1):

Crie um botão do tipo hidden e coloque o valor nele:

```
    <form method="GET" action="imprimirRel.php">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $func; ?>" name="submit"/>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" style="<?php echo $mostraTabela ?>">Confirmar saída</button>
    </form>
```

> Nota: A váriavel $func deve conter o valor que deseja passar

Comment: Hiago, acho que não consegui explicar direito. Não gostaria de ter um botão para cada funcionário, mas sim selecionar um funcionário e partir disso preencher o resto do relatório. Pense que estou tentando criar um controle de saída de produtos, e como haverá uma página impressa para assinatura de cada funcionário confirmando os produtos que estão saindo, não convém que seja feito com mais funcionários ao mesmo tempo. Ficou mais claro?

Comment: Sim, me desculpe vou reanalisar e modificar a resposta

Comment: Modifiquei a pergunta, caso a váriavel $func tenha o valor desejado vai ser passado corretamente o valor para a imprimirRel.php

Comment: Editei minha pergunta. Acha que ficou mais claro?

Comment: Sim ficou, mas o @Thiago já lhe deu a solução.